# Laravel login without regenerating session id

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using the artisan generated auth under Laravel 5.4. My application needs to keep the session id on login. I've removed `session()->regenerate()` in `AuthenticatesUsers->sendLoginResponse()` but still getting a new session id on login. I just can't see where this is happening.